# new comint mod in emacs for plink (putty): Symbol's function definition is void

Tags: emacs, putty, plink

i want to use a new comint mode for plink(putty), i put the code in init.el, but if M-x run-plink, i got below error:

**let*: Symbol's function definition is void: comint-check-proc**

```
;; path    
(defvar plink-file-path "C:/Programme/Putty/plink.exe"     
  "Path to the program used by `run-plink'") 

;; arguments
(defvar plink-arguments '() 
  "Commandline arguments to pass to `plink'") 

;; prompt
(defvar plink-prompt-regexp "^>\s" 
"Prompt for `run-plink'.")

;; Run-plink     
(defun run-plink ()     
  "Run an inferior instance of `plink.js' inside Emacs."     
  (interactive)     
  (setq plink-buffer "*Plink*")     
  (let* ((plink-program plink-file-path) (buffer (comint-check-proc "Plink")))     
    ;; pop to the "*plink*" buffer if the process is dead, the 
    ;; buffer is missing or it's got the wrong mode. 
    (pop-to-buffer-same-window 
     (if (or buffer (not (derived-mode-p 'plink-mode)) 
             (comint-check-proc (current-buffer))) 
         (get-buffer-create (or buffer "*Plink*")) 
       (current-buffer))) 
    ;; create the comint process if there is no buffer. 
    (unless buffer 
      (apply 'make-comint-in-buffer "Plink" buffer plink-program plink-arguments) 
      (plink-mode)))) 

;; plink-mode    
(define-derived-mode plink-mode comint-mode "plink" nil "plink"     
  (setq comint-process-echoes t)     
  (setq comint-use-prompt-regexp t)     
  (setq comint-prompt-regexp plink-prompt-regexp)     
  ; ">" read-only    
  (setq comint-prompt-read-only t)     
  (set (make-local-variable 'paragraph-separate) "..'")     
  (set (make-local-variable 'paragraph-start) plink-prompt-regexp))
```

Comment: You should probably move this to a separate file, and reserve `init.el` strictly for your own personal preferences.  The Emacs manual has some additional guidance for how to write modular code.  Start e.g. at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Simple-Extension.html

Comment: thank you. i think, the code runs without separate file. any way, i have to learn some elisp.

Comment: Sure it can be pulled off, it's just a major inconvenience you probably want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not loaded library `comint`.  You need to do that before Emacs can know about `comint-check-proc`.

Add a `(require 'comint)`, either in your init file or near the beginning of `run-plink` - somewhere before it tries to use `comint-check-proc`.

Comment: Hi Drew, thank you. The code is running, but i got "Text is read-only
" and "comint-send-input: Current buffer has no process". There is no prompt Symbol and i can't input.  I just want to have a new comint mode for plink(putty).  I'm new with emacs. Can you please see that again?

Comment: Sorry - only one question per question, please. Please post any other questions separately. This is a Q & A site, not a here-is-my-code-please-debug-it-for-me site. Try to keep questions narrow. Thx.

Comment: Thank you. I post separately.

Comment: How to do this for `gst`?

Comment: @Zelphir: No idea what that means (what's gst?), but it sounds like a separate question (e.g., to be posted).

Comment: @Drew Well, this was marked as a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48418378/1829329 , so I assumed you would know. Would be great if you could clear up the relation between these two.

Comment: That question was marked as duplicate because it was about error `Symbol's function definition is void`.

Answer (score 0):

To give this question an answer, which is also meaningful for other questions marked as duplicates of this one, but actually are about other packages not being loaded, I will give a more general answer, which should be applicable to the other questions as well.

Generally an error `Symbol's function definition is void` often indicates, that a package was not loaded, but then someone/something tried to use it.

So the general answer, that you probably need to `(require '<package name>)` in your `init.el`, where the package name is the name of the package which provides what is currently void.