# Symbol's function definition is void: gst Emacs 24.5 smalltalk-mode

Tags: emacs

I have installed `Gnu-Smalltalk` from `Synaptic Package Manager`. All look fine, but when I run `Emacs`, with a `.st` file loaded, `Smalltalk-mode` become active but I can't run the `Interactor (C-c m)`

This is the message from the mini-buffer

> Symbol's function definition is void: gst

What is wrong?

Thank's for attention.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: The smalltalk-mode work fine but the command to start the Interactor don't start anything and show in the minibuffer the message : Symbol's function definition is void: gst

Comment: The relation between this question and the supposed duplicate is very far from obvious to me.

Comment: In my case the solution was, that I had to `(require 'gst-mode)` in my `init.el`, which apparently I did not do before.